# How to find evenly divisible values in array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

It sounds like the goal is to find the only two numbers in each row where one evenly divides the other - that is, where the result of the division operation is a whole number. They would like you to find those numbers on each line, divide them, and add up each line's result.

For example, given the following spreadsheet:

[5, 9, 2, 8]

[9, 4, 7, 3]

[3, 8, 6, 5]

In the first row, the only two numbers that evenly divide are 8 and 2; the result of this division is 4.
In the second row, the two numbers are 9 and 3; the result is 3.
In the third row, the result is 2.
In this example, the sum of the results would be 4 + 3 + 2 = 9.

Find the evenly divisible values in next array:

[1224, 926, 1380, 688, 845, 109, 118, 88, 1275, 1306, 91, 796, 102, 1361]
[1928, 2097,138, 1824, 198, 117, 1532, 2000, 1478 ,539, 1982]

how to use `for loop` or `reduce` in this case?

https://codepen.io/marinashumeyko/pen/EbreoJ?editors=1011

Comment: Questions asking for _homework_ help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: you want to evenly divide each other or divide them by 2?

Comment: try something yourself using "modulo"...

Comment: By 'evenly divide' you just mean divisible by 2? Note that there is an operator [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) that gives you the remainder of dividing e.g. `4 % 2 == 0; 9 % 2 == 1`. So how could you use that operator to [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) your array?

Comment: you should post what you have tried so far

Comment: yes, @DakshMiglani the task is to find in each row where one evenly divides the other, not by 2

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and modulo `%`

```
const input =  [1224, 926, 1380, 688, 845, 109, 118, 88, 1275, 1306, 91, 796, 102, 1361]
const result = input.filter(val => val %2 === 0);
console.log(result);
```

Well it looks like some scope-creep since i first read this. If you want divisibles between values in the array, then you can do:

```
const input =  [1224, 926, 1380, 688, 6, 3, 845, 109, 118, 88, 1275, 1306, 91, 796, 102, 1361]
const result = input.reduce((acc, val) => {
  const divisibles = input.filter(v => val !== v && val % v === 0).map(v => val / v);
  return [...acc, ...divisibles];
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

You now appear to be using an array of arrays as input; if that is the case then you will have to do a further level of nesting of the above single array example - but it gives you the idea.

Comment: Thanks. But I need to find not `e % 2` but where `input[i] % input[n] === 0 `

Comment: Thanks a lot. Divisible between values in the array, it was exactly what I was looking for. Not familiar with this syntax only `[...acc, ...divisibles]` what this three dots mean?

Comment: it's the spread operator, working like ```Array.prototype.concat``` in this instance. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: also, please can you mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input =  [1224, 926, 1380, 688, 845, 109, 118, 88, 1275, 1306, 91, 796, 102, 1361];
for (i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    for (j = i+1; j<input.length; j++) {
        if (input[i] % input[j] == 0) {
            console.log(input[i] / input[j],'\n',i,input[i],'\n',j,input[j]);
        }
        if (input[j] % input[i] ==0) {
            console.log(input[j] / input[i],'\n',i,input[i],'\n',j,input[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to find even numbers in the array, you can use the `filter` method of the array, and we can apply the standard CS Logic of `Modulo` here:

```
const newArr =  [1224, 926, 1380, 688, 845, 109, 118, 88, 1275, 1306, 91, 796, 102, 1361].filter(e => e % 2 == 0)
console.log(newArr)
```

by `e % 2` we are trying to find if the element e is divisible by 2 or not, if it is then `e % 2` is = 0.